# Variable inside a variable in Jenkinsfile

Tags: variables, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jsonparser

What is the correct `Jenkinsfile` syntax in order to use a variable value when executing command with another variable?

For example:

```
def lastItemIndex = "${json.items.size()-1}"
def path = "${json.items[${lastItemIndex}].assets.downloadUrl}"
echo "${path}"
```

- First variable is `lastItemIndex` and second one is `json`.
- The second row is not running properly when I tried different options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax in your second row is mostly fine. Your problem is that you are storing the return of `lastItemIndex` as a String and then attempting to use it as an Integer in your second row of code.

You can fix your first row with:

```
lastItemIndex = json.items.size() - 1
```

and then it will be an Integer type and `def path = "${json.items[lastItemIndex].assets.downloadUrl}"` will succeed.

Alternatively, you could just have the second line of code with:

```
def path = "${json.items[-1].assets.downloadUrl}"
```

to access the last element of the array.

Note that in general if you need to convert a String to an Integer within a Jenkins Pipeline via Groovy you can utilize the `to_Integer` method.

Comment: Matt thank you very much for your help!
Your suggestion for the first row did help, but the second row ended in exception about the inner $ sign.
Eventually the solution was to write the second row in the same way you suggest for the first row..

That what works for me:
def lastItemIndex = json.items.size()-1
def path = json.items[lastItemIndex].assets.downloadUrl

Comment: @EitanAshtamker Yeah I thought that was what the syntax should be, but still made the typo. Updated the answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Matt, eventually that what works for me:

def lastItemIndex = json.items.size()-1

def path = json.items[lastItemIndex].assets.downloadUrl